# Como mudar a constrains de NULL para NOT NULL

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Quero mudar as seguinte:

```
alter table pessoas
modify sexo not null;
```

dá o seguinte erro : SQL Error [4161] [HY000]: (conn=9) Unknown data type: 'not'

para ilustrar:
[image: DEBEVEAR SGDB]

Comment: Você não deve editar a pergunta para incluir a solução. O correto seria adicionar uma nova resposta.

Answer (score 2):

Uma maneira de resolver o problema é executando um alter table.

A gramática do mysql que define a operação do ***alter table*** é a seguinte:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name
    [alter_option [, alter_option] ...]
    [partition_options]
```

Podemos ver que devemos incluir um ***alter_option***, e não vamos declarar nenhum ***partition_options***.

O alter option que desejamos é definido da seguinte forma:

```
| MODIFY [COLUMN] col_name column_definition
        [FIRST | AFTER col_name]
```

Em relação ao comando que executou, deve adicionar a `column_definition`.

Agora basta montar um DDL correspondente.
Segue um exemplo:

```
ALTER TABLE pessoas MODIFY COLUMN sexo enum('M','F') NOT NULL;
```

Outra alternativa seria omitir a palavra chave `column`, já que não é obrigatório:

```
ALTER TABLE pessoas MODIFY sexo enum('M','F') NOT NULL;
```

Você pode consultar a [documentação](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html) para mais opções.

Comment: Obrigado . achei uma aqui na documentação. https://www.mariadbtutorial.com/mariadb-basics/mariadb-not-null/